# Drag and Drop UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

Нужно иметь возможность добавлять изображения в приложение путем перетаскивания из файловой системы

У `Grid` включил `AllowDrop`. Но как добавить перетаскиваемые изображения в коллекцию? Т.к. те примеры что видел, добавляют изображения только в кодбихайнд.

Написал метод в контроле

```
 private void Grid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;

        if (e.DragUIOverride != null)
        {
            e.DragUIOverride.Caption = "Add file";
            e.DragUIOverride.IsContentVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

`XAML`

```
<Grid    
    Width="2560" 
    Height="1600"
    Margin="0,0,0,0" 
    AllowDrop="True"
    Drop=" "
    DragOver="Grid_DragOver"
    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center">



  <Image
     Width="525"
     Height="331"
     Tapped="Image_Tapped"
     Source="{x:Bind Image}"
     Margin="{x:Bind Margins}"
     DoubleTapped="Image_DoubleTapped"
     RightTapped="Image_RightTapped"
     ManipulationDelta="Image_ManipulationDelta"
     ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY,Rotate,Scale">
         <Image.RenderTransform>
             <CompositeTransform/>
         </Image.RenderTransform>
  </Image>
```

Метод `Drop` посылаю в команду на ВМ, там по идее должен добавить полученные картинки в `ObservableCollection`, в которой они хранятся.(Приложение должно иметь 2 вида загрузки картинок, через пикер и дроп). Не понял как мне их там получить. Я же не могу с `View` в `VM` передать аргумент `DragEventArgs e` или могу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал `Drop` метод в контроле

```
 private async void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
        {
            var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
            {
                ViewModelLocator.ManipulatorInstance.TempFiles.Add(items[i] as StorageFile);
            }
            ViewModelLocator.ManipulatorInstance.DropFilesExecute();
        }
    }
```

В цикле закинул в `List<StorageFile>` на ВМ и вызвал метод с ВМ, который уже добавляет в коллекцию

Comment: Upd, поскольку codebahind это не хорошо, написал `Dependency Property `и `Behavior`, там получаю данные и передаю в команду на `ViewModel`